For a Nqbit, prove that $\langle|\alpha_i|^2\rangle=1/2^N$ and that $\langle|\alpha_i \alpha_j|^2\rangle= 2^{\delta_{ij}-N}/(1+2^N) $
In the following article it is written that:

This is done by using spherical coordinates in a $2^N$ -dimensional real space,where $N$ is the number of qubits to be teleported. We thus find that  $\langle|\alpha_i|^2\rangle=1/2^N$ and that $\langle|\alpha_i \alpha_j|^2\rangle= 2^{\delta_{ij}-N}/(1+2^N) $, which is all that is required in the following calculations. Here, $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and zero otherwise.

So I tried to understand how did they get to this result.
I begin to do it with in the simple case of one qubit ($N=1$) but I did not succeed. Indeed I tried with the distribution of the uniform probability on a sphere but I did not succeed and the distribution function they used to get this result is not precised.

averaging over these quantities with the appropriate distribution function.

Anyone to show me the calculus and help me to understand, because I am really stuck.

The claim certainly works for a single qubit. Here, you should think of
$$
\alpha_0=\cos\frac{\theta}{2},\qquad \alpha_1=\sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}.
$$
So, you can readily calculate, for example, the average of $|\alpha_0|^2$, you just have to be careful of the region that you're integrating over. In this case, it's the surface of a sphere in 3 dimensions (the Bloch sphere). So, you have
$$
\langle|\alpha_0|^2\rangle=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\theta d\theta=\frac12.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\langle|\alpha_0\alpha_1|^2\rangle=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\theta d\theta=\frac16.
$$
As an approach for more qubits, I'd start from the idea that $\alpha_x=\langle x|\psi\rangle$ for an arbitrary $|\psi\rangle$. Now $\sum_x|\alpha_x|^2=1$ by normalisation. However, you'd hopefully agree that the average value $\langle|\alpha_x|\rangle^2$ should be independent of $x$. That must mean that $\langle\sum_x|\alpha_x|^2\rangle=\sum_x\langle|\alpha_x|^2\rangle=2^N\langle|\alpha_x|^2\rangle=1$. Thus, the single expectation is exactly as claimed.
The trick for the cross terms is to think of $|\alpha_i\alpha_j|^2$ as an off-diagonal element ($i\neq j$) of the density matrix of two copies:
$$
|\alpha_i\alpha_j|^2=\langle ij|(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|^{\otimes 2})|ji\rangle
$$
Next, rewrite $|\psi\rangle=U|0\rangle$ (where I'm using $|0\rangle$ to represent the all-0 state of $N$ qubits). You can calculate
$$
\int dU (U|0\rangle\langle 0|U^\dagger)^{\otimes 2}.
$$
The result is known as 'twirling'. I forget exactly what the result is: in a quantum information context, twirling is usually using $U\otimes U^\star$. I guess, without having checked carefully, you can transform the quantity to
$$
\langle|\alpha_i\alpha_j|^2\rangle=\langle ii|\int dU (U\otimes U^\star)|00\rangle\langle 00|(U^\dagger\otimes U^T)|jj\rangle.
$$
Again, I forget exactly what the result is, but $\int dU (U\otimes U^\star)|00\rangle\langle 00|(U^\dagger\otimes U^T)$ is some amount of identity and some amount of a projection onto the maximally entangled state. That should yield the result you're after!

Thank for your help, I am going to look more closer to it (because i ve tried this way and didn't get good enough results).

Thank. Further more what does represent the quantities $<| \alpha_0 \alpha_1|^2 >$ ? If I am not wrong $<|\alpha_1|^2>$ is the expected value of measuring the value $ \alpha_1 $ is it correct?

Thank a lot for your time and answer. I did not understood very weel the last part ,from  "of the density matrix of two copies:" , (I am an undergraduate student and a more devellop answer should be necessary). But again thk a lot for your time as it is the only answer I ve found on this subject.
